# How to float these boxes so that they fit snug together?

Tags: html, css

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TcvFp/1/)

### html

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac magna non augue porttitor scelerisque ac id diam. Mauris elit velit, lobortis sed interdum at, vestibulum vitae libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque iaculis ligula ut ipsum mattis viverra. Nulla a libero metus. Integer gravida tempor metus eget condimentum. Integer eget iaculis tortor. Nunc sed ligula sed augue rutrum ultrices eget nec odio.. </div>
<div class="box">Fusce a metus eu diam varius congue nec nec sapien. Vestibulum orci tortor, sollicitudin ac euismod non, placerat ac augue. Nunc convallis accumsan justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec malesuada vehicula lectus, viverra sodales ipsum gravida nec. Integer gravida nisi ut magna mollis molestie. Nullam pharetra accumsan sagittis. Proin tristique rhoncus orci, eget vulputate nisi sollicitudin et. Quisque lacus augue, mollis non mollis et, ullamcorper in purus. Morbi et sem orci. Praesent accumsan odio in ante ullamcorper id pellentesque mauris rhoncus. Duis vitae neque dolor. Duis sed purus at eros bibendum cursus nec a nulla. Donec turpis quam, ultricies id pretium sit amet, gravida eget leo. 
</div>
<div class="box">Vivamus vulputate mattis magna ac pretium. Nulla facilisi. Praesent ut quam quam. Suspendisse non lorem at ligula convallis convallis. Phasellus varius, felis nec ultrices pulvinar, tortor massa semper nunc, id auctor elit felis eget libero. Sed in turpis quam. In ultrices, eros sit amet vehicula mattis, nisi nisi tincidunt neque, a imperdiet lorem nibh eget libero. Vivamus tempus nunc odio, ut iaculis nunc.</div>
<div class="box">Donec vel sapien lacus, sed lobortis nisl. Integer a dui nulla, non convallis massa. Quisque posuere lobortis purus id rutrum. Ut congue, leo ut venenatis pharetra, enim mi luctus nisi, eget sollicitudin dolor sapien ut felis. Etiam a augue nisi, vel vehicula erat. Nullam ultricies massa lectus. Vestibulum et viverra est. Vestibulum vulputate fringilla augue, non interdum enim ultrices sed. Vivamus sagittis pretium tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed accumsan condimentum eros vitae scelerisque.</div>
<div class="box">Phasellus turpis augue, semper id facilisis a, ultrices vel purus. Donec ut risus purus, non convallis justo. Sed tempor consectetur condimentum. Fusce ipsum nulla, porta et euismod eget, aliquam sit amet nisi. Phasellus tempus enim in nisl porta placerat. Vivamus lectus turpis, tincidunt eget pellentesque et, malesuada sit amet diam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam tristique mollis ligula, non sagittis justo interdum sit amet. Cras blandit turpis ut lorem adipiscing convallis. Donec ultrices erat at massa vehicula sit amet feugiat purus accumsan. Sed quis lacus sem, sed pretium orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam suscipit, velit nec ultrices porttitor, libero arcu vulputate nisi, ut lacinia massa lectus et nulla.</div>
</div>​
```

### css

```
#container { 
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.box {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
​
```

I essentially want it so that the 3rd box ("Vivamus vulputate") fits snug up against the first box ("Lorem ipsum").

I know there's a way to do this using some CSS wizardry, I just can't remember how...

Answer (score 4):

Such is the nature of the web, that is why `jQuery Masonry` was born:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

---

The layout, as it currently is, cannot accommodate your desired result. However, you could achieve something similar by defining all "left" `.box` columns `float:left; clear:left;` and all "right" `.box` columns `float:right; clear:right;` ...

**Result:**

http://jsfiddle.net/TcvFp/3/

Comment: I was hoping I could have them just "flow" into which ever column they fit best such that the columns become roughly even height, but I can make do with this.

Comment: Correct, this wouldn't be an issue if all the `.box`es had the same height

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work that well either. If we [reduce the sizes of all the boxes in one column](http://jsfiddle.net/TcvFp/4/), they get aligned with a box in the other column. My boxes have a dynamic height, so this won't work.

Comment: @mark Right, didn't see that one coming ... Given the nature of `CSS` floats, I don't think you're going to get the desired outcome without `JS` ... Though, you could always add another container to represent the column http://jsfiddle.net/TcvFp/5/

Comment: Never seen that masonry plugin. Looks wicked. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Such magic is indeed exists and is called css columns: http://jsfiddle.net/JyVUD/ (example for webkit, to make it work in FF and Opera simply add needed prefixes).

But as it often happens with such magic, certain browser e.g. IE, didn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

This is done with some JavaScript [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TcvFp/7/), I kept it plain (I'd of used mootools) as thats how you had setup the Fiddle.

I works but I'm sure it could be done better/neeter and probably isn't cross browser capable, but I'll post so you can see.